# Jquery Validation remote validation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-validate

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am using the Jquery.Validate plugin and it has a remote field, so I did this:

```
$("#mainForm").validate(
    {
        rules:
        {
            UserName:
            {
                required: true
               ,remote: "Test"
            }
         ,messages:
        {
            UserName:
            {
                remote: "UserName has already been chosen. Please choose another one"
            }
        }

     }
```

The required works fine. It's the remote that has the problem. I am using asp.net MVC and the path is right - it hits my method

```
public bool Test(string userName)
{
    return false;
}
```

It returns false according to firebug yet jquery.validate does not kick in. I am using Version 1.5.5 of jquery.validate and jquery 1.3.2

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got caught out by this one also.

You need to return a Json object with true or false, see below:

```
    public ActionResult IsValidField()
    {
        String the_field = httpContextService.Request["Field_To_Test"];

        if (the_field == another_value)
          return Json(true);
        else 
          return Json(false);
    }
```

Comment: This is really messed up . I found that the  in jQuery after hours of struggle the  dataFilter which returned plan boolean true/false was reject by $.parseJSON method .  Now the solution seems to be  return $.toJSON(true) or return $.toJSON(false)