# Asp.Net WebForm JQuery remote Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, validation, webforms

I want to do exactly the same thing that in this question : [Jquery Validation remote validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249709/jquery-validation-remote-validation-not-working)

The only thing that change is that I'm using Asp.Net WebForm instead of Asp.Net MVC. So, the solution proposed in this post doesn't work for me...

### UPDATE

From Jeff comment, here's my new try:

```
$("#mainForm").validate(
{
    rules:
    {
        UserName:
        {
            required: true
           ,remote: "IsValidField"
        }
     ,messages:
    {
        UserName:
        {
            remote: "UserName has already been choosen. Please choose another one"
        }
    }

 }
```

c#

```
public String IsValidField()
{
    String the_field = Request["Field_To_Test"];
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    if (the_field == another_value)
        return serializer.Serialize(true);
    else
        return serializer.Serialize(true);
}
```

If I put a breakpoint the method is never call...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of webforms or MVC, your page method still has to return a JSON object.  So the solution in that post should work fine in a ASP.NET Webforms project.

Comment: Can you provide me an example of how I can return a JSON object because I didn't find this namespace. I didn't find the ActionResult namespace either. So, I don't understand how I can use the proposed solution.

Comment: You can use Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer to create the json object.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you should try

`/IsValidField`

the problem is your path